# add a new default route to Route::resource for each resource controller

Tags: laravel-8

I modify "controller.stub" file in stubs directory and i add a new method "details" for each resource controllers

```
<?php
namespace {{ namespace }};

use {{ rootNamespace }}Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class {{ class }} extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

public function details()
{
    //
}
}
```

but now when i use "Route::resource('foo', foo::class)" method in web.php file,
there is not any registered route for "details".
how can i modify default routes of Route::resource('foo', foo::class) for my new function in resource controller?